# Java parsing JSON in args

Tags: java, json

Can you anyone help me with problem of parsing args in java?

I need to read JSON data by `args` in two formats(file, text arg). If an arg is path to file with JSON text, it's working.

In main method I'm reading args:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  String argText = args[1]
}
```

But if I'm put to arg some JSON text (for example: *{"server1":{"dname":"www.server.com","lat":"40","lng":"17"}*) it's problem with quotes, because in
`String argText` is  stored text without quotes:

```
System.out.println("Text: " + argText);

Text: {server1:{dname:www.server.com,lat:40,lng:17}
```

And method for parsing JSON:

```
public static JSONObject parseJSON(String argText){
  if (text.contains("{")){
     //arg is text and I want to store it as JSONObject 
     // how to store text with "

  } else {
     //argText is file....
     // read file, put in new JSONObject
     // it works without any problems.
 }

return JsonObject
}
```

I don't know it is the good way to read input args, but for file it's working and I would to add reading form the text.

If  `argText` contains escaped quotes  `\\\"` everythig is OK, but I don't have text in these format.

EDIT:

So I don't have problem with parsing JSON bud I need some method that doing:

```
public static void(String quotedText){

  //do something...
  System.out.print("Output: " + text);
}
```

with in/out:

```
< '"text":"val1","val2","val3"'
Output: "text":"val1","val2","val3"
```

In Win `system.out.print` is:

```
'Output: text:val1,val2,val3'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using library does not suit your needs, you can make a simple method to covert it. 
Add `"` after every `{`, before every `}`, and both before and after every `,` and `:`.
There might be some ambiguity with those chars, but that why quotes are supposed to be there at first place.

Comment: Thanks for idea, I resolve it by this way. Maybe not good way but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The quotes are munged by the shell; put the whole string in single quotes for that to work. If your utility is launched by some other program, fix that program to escape everything, or transport it using stdin.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use some standard library for parsing JSON, it will really save you a lot of time. JSON isn't that simple that you can just treat it like a simple string.

Try:
http://jackson.codehaus.org/

https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

Answer (score 0):

You should try a standard library to parse JSON, like Alexander said.

There are some out there that convert JSON into Java objects. I personally like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/). Try this [JSON with Xtream tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html)

With it, you can define your own Java objects and use the library to convert JSON to those objects and from the objects to JSON. No need to create your own parser.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this simple and widely used library: [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)